# Example of commuting field automorphisms that don't extend to algebraic closure?

Tags: commutative-algebra, galois-theory

Is there an example of a field $K$ of characteristic 0 that has two commuting automorphisms f and g that *cannot* be extended to some automorphisms $\tilde{f}$ and $\tilde{g}$ on the algebraic closure $\bar{K}$ so that $\tilde{f}$ and $\tilde{g}$ would still commute?

Comment: This has been answered at [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/284559/extending-commuting-automorphisms-of-a-field).

Comment: I was looking for a concrete example and couldn't find it from that other answer.

Comment: What about the Heisenberg examples? There the commutativity fails on the algebraic closure.